# Dynamically Create Multiple Elements (Sliders/Carousels)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

For my current project I'm trying to add dynamically mutliple sliders/carousels (I'm using the owl carousel):

First I initialize the carousel (after including the necessary js/css):

```
<div class="search-carousel owl-carousel carousel-home">
   <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/img/sample/place1.jpg"></div>
   <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/img/sample/place2.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Now I load multiple of these ^ on page load and dynamically after ajax requests, since my jQuery looks like this:

```
/* OWL CAROUSEL */
    var owlhome = $(".search-carousel");
    owlhome.owlCarousel({
        items : 4,
        lazyLoad : true,
        navigation : false
    });
    $(".arr-left").click(function(){
        owlhome.trigger('owl.prev');
    });
    $(".arr-right").click(function(){
        owlhome.trigger('owl.next');
    });
```

How can I make the plugin work as I add more sliders dynamically? **I created a jsFiddle** example to show how the plugin doesn't act on new carousels that are added dynamically:

https://jsfiddle.net/kz3c6L64/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean, adding more slides to existing carousel?

Answer (score 0):

By assigning `foo.innerHTML` you are destroying all of the DOM elements that the Owl code attached to in the `owlCarousel` call.

The documentation contains information about methods to add and remove items. That seems like a better way to do what you want to do: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/manipulations.html

Comment: hello! what I need is to create a brand new Carousel not just adding items (as the documentation suggests), thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to create a function that both adds a new carousel and then binds it, e.g.

```
var carouselTemplate = '<div class="block"><a class="arr-left">LT</a> <a class="arr-right">RT</a> <div class="owl-carousel"><div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ud2JynQ.jpg" width:="100" height="50"/></div><div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ud2JynQ.jpg" width:="70" height="50"/></div><div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ud2JynQ.jpg" width:="100" height="50"/></div></div></div>';

function createAndBindCarousel($element) {
    // Carousel template
    var $owlCarousel = $(carouselTemplate);

    // Insert carousel into element
    $element.append($owlCarousel);

    // Bind carousel
    $owlCarousel.owlCarousel({
        items : 4,
        lazyLoad : true,
        navigation : false
    });

    // Left arrow
    $owlCarousel.find(".arr-left").click(function(){
      $owlCarousel.trigger('owl.prev');
    });

    // Right arrow
    $owlCarousel.find(".arr-right").click(function(){
      $owlCarousel.trigger('owl.next');
    });
}

// Add a new carousel to #carousels
createAndBindCarousel($("#carousels"));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the example [here](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/manipulations.html), you need to follow the following formatted function call:

```
owlcarousel.data('owlCarousel').addItem('<div>my html markup</div>');
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kz3c6L64/9/)

**If you were looking to create additional carousels, you just need to initialize the carousel object after adding its HTML to the DOM.**

```
$('.class-that-match-your-carousel-attribute').owlCarousel();
```

When you're using the above, you'll have to make sure the class is also being assigned to the HTML element you are adding to the DOM.

[Fiddle where carousel is added](https://jsfiddle.net/kz3c6L64/10/)

Comment: hello! what I need is to create a brand new Carousel not just adding items, thank you for your help

Comment: @user3709532 I see what you mean.  You were pretty close, just had to initialize the carousel object

Comment: thank you for your help but when you add multiple carousels you can notice the others stop working :/